# what is mysql stored procedure if statement structure

Tags: mysql, if-statement, stored-procedures

```
CREATE PROCEDURE PROCEDURENAME()
BEGIN
    IF ((CONDITION),SELECT 0, SELECT 1)); //not working
    IF condition THEN statement END IF; //not working
    IF condition
        statement //not working
END
```

How should I properly write the if statement structure? Anyone have a working example? Please help me.

Comment: Sorry for poor structure. I'm using mobile and I don't have the android app version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clearly read the last stored procedure structure on the below page

http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-if-statement/

please use your code like this one or simply put your code and condition in below code so I will make it fix

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE PROCEDURE `proc_IF` (IN param1 INT)
BEGIN
    DECLARE variable1 INT;
    SET variable1 = param1 + 1;

    IF variable1 = 0 THEN
        SELECT variable1;
    END IF;

    IF param1 = 0 THEN
        SELECT 'Parameter value = 0';
    ELSE
        SELECT 'Parameter value <> 0';
    END IF;
END //
```

Comment: I have read a lot of documentation and tried a lot of examples unfortunately nothing works. I am using xampp with mariadB. I have also checked the mariadB tutorial and tried their example but nothing. The if statement always giving me an error. Even those basic ones. That is why i am asking for a working example so i cant try it out.

Comment: The syntax given above is correct. I don't know what else you are doing, but if you are using the multiline syntax with a single semi-colon at the end (and any for statements contained in the blocks of the IF), then the problem is elsewhere. Without code, we cannot know.

Comment: @smehsoud-- yah this one works. But one more thing, when i construct it using the xampp sql tab for queries(providing not and the same dilimeter w/c i believe has nothing to do with it). It is giving a lot of errors. Copy pasting works though in the "edit line" console. Thank you  very much for this example. Finally i can go on with my life.